# Getting SPWeb in feature receiver

Tags: feature-activation, spweb

While testing my solution I receive an error on Feature activation:

> Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object.  Please close SPWeb objects when you are done with all objects obtained from them, but not before.

This is the way I'm getting SPWeb:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    using (SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
    {
        ClassOfMine.doYourStuff(web);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never dispose a web or site you didn't create.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

how about;

warning: your feature needs to be scoped as web for it to work obviously ;)

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
  // No need to dispose the web istance, as indicated in the "Do not dispose" guidance
  SPWeb web = (SPWeb) properties.Feature.Parent; // added semicolon            

  ClassOfMine.doYourStuff(web);

}
```

---

not using feature:

if not then use the spcontext to get the root web

```
SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb
```

or  - for the current web

```
SPContext.Current.Web
```

or  - for a specific web url

```
SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("Website_URL"))
```

---

to use above in feature you would need to use the properties:

use the properties to get the site to get the rootWeb

```
SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
{

}
```

or  - for the current web

```
SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
```

or  - for a specific web url

```
SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("Website_URL"))
{

}
```

Comment: SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb worked for me in a way. Thanks :-)

Comment: +1 for the answer, I only edited a little imprecision. Hope you don't mind (as told you on meta, I prefer to improve a valid answer ^_^). See this link for other info http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2009/11/30/sharepoint-2007-2010-do-not-dispose-guidance-spdisposecheck.aspx

Comment: lol no probs ;)

Comment: Is SPContext available in the event/feature receivers? I thought that the only way to access it was using properties..?

Comment: @variable yes your right ;) , didnt spot that myself! I think for the op the solution was the first part, as for the second part iv modified it to explain it better :)

Comment: don't dispose .RootWeb object manually!

Comment: @dbardakov yes your correct but depends on what version of SP your using 2003 and 2007 you need to dispose. but in 2010+ its handled by SharePoint. Should of noted it tbh :) as the op never mentioned what version i just assumed at the time it was for 2007

Comment: never dispose a site or web you didn't create.

Comment: as noted disposing of rootweb from SPContext is related to what version of sharepoint you are using. SPContext openweb requires disposal. so in this instance changing older code from rootweb to openweb and encapsulating with using statement on openweb would do the job as openweb creates a new object. also @x0n your commenting on a old thread that was related to 2007 which is different to what you would do today ;) and clear in my answer i do not use a using statement on on the features web object :)

Comment: @aliSharepoint Not quite correct: If you dig into the disposal logic for webs created through OpenWeb, you'll see that they are managed by the SPSite instance that created them. When the SPSite is disposed, all webs created through OpenWeb calls on that site will also be disposed. Not many people know that, as it is not documented. Of course, if you want to eagerly dispose, that's your call but it's not required.

Comment: i think you need to read my comment above "as noted disposing of rootweb from SPContext is related to what version of sharepoint " like i said depends on the version. Pre-2010 you had to because openweb creates a new object that wasn't handled under the dispose object of the spcontext. There are many threads here on stackexchange about this very issue and i have wrote a big article on this outlining this very simple mistake, it was such a problem that Microsoft released an update to add it within the disposable method so you don't have to call it yourself,

Comment: if you have coded from 2003 to 2016 you would know very well that in 2003 and 2007 disposing of objects was an issue, so much that Microsoft released many articles on the subject. I am referring to the code where it doesnt use "new" but does use openweb SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("Website_URL"))  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248(v=office.12).aspx like i said 2010+ its not an issue. ;) btw i do agree that you shouldn't dispose of objects that are already handled by the idisposable but in this case its not pre 2010 and is well documented by Microsoft .

Answer (score 0):

You're doing right. Just the scope of the feature must be web. The "Parent" attribute is always the object of the feature scope.

You're also disposing the object with using.

The only problem with SPContext is that you can't activate the feature from PowerShell as there is no http context.